# Need help to implement mobile inputs in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, touchscreen

I designed a 2d game using Unity 2D game kit. My sole purpose was to release them on Android devices. but unfortunately, its inputs do not work for touchscreen. I want to move the player using a virtual joystick. Can somebody help me to edit this C# script?

```
public InputButton Pause = new InputButton(KeyCode.Escape, XboxControllerButtons.Menu);
    public InputButton Interact = new InputButton(KeyCode.E, XboxControllerButtons.Y);
    public InputButton MeleeAttack = new InputButton(KeyCode.K, XboxControllerButtons.X);
    public InputButton RangedAttack = new InputButton(KeyCode.O, XboxControllerButtons.B);
    public InputButton Jump = new InputButton(KeyCode.Space, XboxControllerButtons.A);
    public InputAxis Horizontal = new InputAxis(KeyCode.D, KeyCode.A, XboxControllerAxes.LeftstickHorizontal);
    public InputAxis Vertical = new InputAxis(KeyCode.W, KeyCode.S, XboxControllerAxes.LeftstickVertical);
    [HideInInspector]
    public DataSettings dataSettings;
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp2PiFC9sSs) help your problem?

Comment: No. I tried it..

Answer (score 0):

You could download an asset from the asset store to do touch controls.

Alternatively you could program them yourself. You can get all the information about how the user has been touching the screen from [Input.Touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html)
To make a virtual joystick you would want to compare the current position of a touch to its position on the frame it's Phase was TouchPhase.Began